# How to write the if else condition inside the list python?

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, python-3.x, django-views

I got the pixel size for the image , i need to write a if condition at the pixel

if jpg or tiff: do something
else '0,0'

How can i write in the below code ?

```
def get(self, request, **response_kwargs):    

    main_request = MediaRequest.objects.get(request_unique_id=self.kwargs['request_unique_id'])

    files = MediaFile.objects.filter(request=main_request)

    files_list = []

    for media_file in files:
        files_list.append ({
                'preview' : "/render/" + str(main_request.request_unique_id) + "/" + media_file.filename,        
                'name' : media_file.filename,        
                'status' : media_file.status,
                'comment' : media_file.comment,
                'id':media_file.id,
                'pixel' : 
                           if "jpg" not in media_file.filename:
                              Image.open(settings.MEDIA_ROOT + main_request.request_unique_id + "/"+ media_file.filename).size
                           else:
                               return '0, 0'
            })
```

Comment: if "jpg" not in media_file.filename:
      ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax   it giving

Comment: I'm not able to reproduce your error. However, just pointing out that you run the risk of a file having jpg in the filename, even if it isn't a jpg file. Would it be better (and more efficient) to check if the last 4 letters in the filename are '.jpg' instead?

Comment: How to write the if else condition to find the .jpg and tif and then excute the image.open command ...else need to return 0,0 ?

Answer (score 0):

See ternary operator (or conditional expression): `"X if C else Y"`

https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0308/

```
for media_file in files:
    files_list.append ({
            'preview' : "/render/" + str(main_request.request_unique_id) + "/" + media_file.filename,        
            'name' : media_file.filename,        
            'status' : media_file.status,
            'comment' : media_file.comment,
            'id':media_file.id,
            'pixel' : Image.open(settings.MEDIA_ROOT + main_request.request_unique_id + "/"+ media_file.filename).size if "jpg" not in media_file.filename else '0, 0'
        })
```

Comment: `code 'File "/views.py", line 374, in get
    'pixel' : Image.open(settings.MEDIA_ROOT + main_request.request_unique_id + "/"+ media_file.filename).size if "jpg" not in media_file.filename else '0, 0'                })
  File "/PIL/Image.py", line 2286, in open
    % (filename if filename else fp))
OSError: cannot identify image file '/pathof file/testfile.pdf'`  still getting the error

Answer (score 0):

```
 'pixel' : Image.open(settings.MEDIA_ROOT + main_request.request_unique_id 
+ "/"+ media_file.filename).size if ("JPG" in media_file.filename.upper()) 
or ("TIF"  in media_file.filename.upper())  else '0, 0'}
```